# Can i have a view stub on top of TabActivity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I am having four tabs in my tab activity and I need a toolbar with three buttons on top of tabactivity irrespective of current tab selection.

Can I use viewstub for this?

Could anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="woopra" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>       
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="gone"/>            
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="64dip">
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/dashboard_tab" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler" android:text="Dashboard"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/visitors_tab" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler" android:text="Vistors"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/chat_tab" android:onClick="tabHandler"
                android:text="Chat"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/reports_tab" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler" android:text="Reports"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
                 android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the framelayout with id 'tabcontent' is where the content of our tab goes to. What ever you put outside this framwlayout will be in the tab activity irrespective of the tab selected.

If you look on the top of the xml you can see a linearlayout with id 'header'. This is a heading layout that I made which will always be visible in the tab layout. You can do the same to create a toolbar by putting buttons instead of  textviews like ive done.

Comment: Set this answer. It will help future users and even you for future  references.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your toolbar in the layout, what's the problem?

Comment: How to define that toolbar to the tabactivity's layout?

Comment: Make a regular layout, and set the id of the tabhost.to @android:id/tabs. Actually.it should have that id by default.

Comment: I have four tabs and four activity in a well established manner. But added to that, I need a tool bar on top of every activity associated with each tab.